# Google UI App Scripts: Create a Google Doc with a legal paper size and landscape layout

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Using Google UI App Scripts how can you create a new Google Doc with a legal paper size and landscape layout? From the [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) page I see how you can create a new document and edit a lot of the elements but not the page size or layout orientation. Am I missing it? Or is this something that is not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Paper size of the document can be set using [setPageHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setPageHeight(Number)) and [setPageWidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setPageWidth(Number)) methods of the class [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)

```
  function setPageSize(){
    var doc = DocumentApp.create("file name");
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var pointsInInch = 72;
    body.setPageHeight(6.5 * pointsInInch);  //6.5 - inches
    body.setPageWidth(4 * pointsInInch); // 4 - inches
  }
```