# How can I create a document with horizontal page orientation using google doc api

Tags: python, google-docs-api

How can I create a document with horizontal page orientation (landscape) using google doc api (in python if possible)

Comment: [`DocumentStyle`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#documentstyle) has a `PageSize` of type [`Size`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#size) where `height` and `width` is specified.

Comment: See also [Google UI App Scripts: Create a Google Doc with a legal paper size and landscape layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943661/google-ui-app-scripts-create-a-google-doc-with-a-legal-paper-size-and-landscape).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have requested that that question have the [google-docs-api] tag removed as it does not pertain to this question which is actually about the google docs api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one was hard. For future generations:

```py
body = {
    'title': 'Doc1'
}

doc = service.documents() \
    .create(body=body).execute()

file_id = doc.get('documentId')
requests =[
    {'updateDocumentStyle':{
        "documentStyle":{
            'pageSize':{
                  "height": {
                        'magnitude': 8.27,
                        'unit': 'PT'
                    },
                  "width": {
                        'magnitude': 11.69,
                        'unit': 'PT'
                    }
                }},
        "fields": 'pageSize'
        
    }}]
result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

Comment: Got a weird result with those values, 3000+ pages and 0 left and right margins and the page seemed to be 1mm wide. Using the values width:842 height:595 works for me and shows "A4" and "Landscape" in the page settings, which is what I need. FYI I scoured the docs and total missed that. Really appreciate the complete example!

Comment: I think there is typo: 'magnitude': 1.69 - should be 11.69

Comment: @noors I don't have the ability to check it right now, but I think you are right

Comment: @Oren - your answer enabled me to solve the same problem.  The reason that rob got the weird result was that your magnitudes were in inches instead of pts.  That's why 842x595 fixed it for him.  For 8.5 x 11 the dimensions that worked for me were 792x612.  You might want to edit your answer at some point, but thanks!